# Label's text appeared nothing when is session over from the first page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to Session over my Label.Text in the first .aspx page to another Label in the second .aspx page. I retrieve my value from the database and place them in the first Label.Text and want to Session this Label (Which i got the text from the database) to another page linked to the first page. I use this method is because i have a detailed products page (My first .aspx page) which consists of many products and when user click a particular product, it's product name have to be displayed in the second page of the .aspx . My problem here is that when i Session over the Label's text on the first page, the value does not pass over to another page.

My first page's .cs code (code behind):

```
Session["productName"] = productName.Text;
    Response.Redirect("products2.aspx");
```

My second page's .cs code (code behind - I place this code in page load)

```
if (Session["productName"] != null)
        productName.Text = Session["productName"].ToString();
```

Have i gone wrong anywhere?

Comment: Extend the session timeout in the `web.config` file like this: `<sessionState timeout="3000"></sessionState>`

Comment: Your code looks OK. Question is: when is it executed? First part of code should be placed in button click event or something like that. Second part should be in page_load event of products2.aspx.

Comment: My first part of the code is written in a LinkButton such that when this linkButton is clicked, the product name will appear on products2.aspx. I included the second part of the code in page_load already. But nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to make the session not to be expired for a long time, you should follow two steps.

```
Keep a continous eye on the Session Timeout.
Redirect the session when its about to expire.
```

The Base Page for Detecting Sessions will explain you every thing you need to do, please refer it once.

Answer (score 0):

your code is totally right..
but my question is are you using ispostback in your page load??

if not then use it like this..because of postback sometimes you can't get values.
then put your code if is not postback

```
page_load()
{
if(ispostback)
{

}
else
{
//put your code here
}
}
```